# Distribution of Badugi Hands

Tags: poker-theory, odds

I'd like to know when you're dealt a badugi in [Badugi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badugi), where does that hand stand in relation to another random badugi hand? i.e. both hands have four different suits and ranks.

- Example 1: I'm dealt a J-high badugi (Jh 8s 7d 3c). Roughly speaking, what are the odds that I'm ahead of another random badugi?

Implicitly, assume you stand pat on all three rounds.

Comment: what are you looking for? a number? or how to play such a hand?

Comment: Are you also assuming your opponents stand pat? If not, what are they drawing to?

Comment: Yeah, it's as though you're all-in in round 1, and everyone stands pat each round

Comment: Really didn't understand whats this question contribute. All you want is how many hands you can beat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was thinking about how to explain my question a bit more and then realised I could work out the answer.

I wrote a small python script to count all the badugis one can be dealt.

```
715 badugis in total
  4 high:    1,  0.1% of tot. Cum   1,  0.1% of total
  5 high:    4,  0.6% of tot. Cum   5,  0.7% of total
  6 high:   10,  1.4% of tot. Cum  15,  2.1% of total
  7 high:   20,  2.8% of tot. Cum  35,  4.9% of total
  8 high:   35,  4.9% of tot. Cum  70,  9.8% of total
  9 high:   56,  7.8% of tot. Cum 126, 17.6% of total
 10 high:   84, 11.7% of tot. Cum 210, 29.4% of total
  J high:  120, 16.8% of tot. Cum 330, 46.2% of total
  Q high:  165, 23.1% of tot. Cum 495, 69.2% of total
  K high:  220, 30.8% of tot. Cum 715, 100.0% of total
```

To answer my example, a J-hi badugi is a favorite (53.8%) over any random badugi.
Nearly 31% of all dealt badugis are K-high etc.

Comment: I purposefully ignored suits because it doesn't change the answer. Surely there are 4!=24 combinations of suits for each badugi, regardless of level. So the 24 is a constant factor and doesn't affect the result.

Comment: nice work man;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try my badugi simulator.  http://pokervane.com/badugi_simulator

Comment: I put 2 hearts in there and the equity actually increased from 33 % (which was before) to 37 % ...

Comment: @SoboLAN I have no idea what that comment means.

Comment: OK, so I put 2 Badugi hands there (4 different cards of 4 different ranks and 4 different suits). And made them... battle it out. So I got equity 33 % in one hand vs 66 % in the other. The first one had a heart and a club in it. So I removed the club and put another heart in there, which means it contained 2 hearts. Which means it wasn't a Badugi hand anymore. I made them "battle" it out again. So this time the equities were 37 % vs. 62 %. Shouldn't it be 0 % vs. 100 % ? (because 2 hearts means no Badugi which means no winning)

Comment: @SoboLan please send me that exact cards you were using for each simulation and I will take a look.  Also, please confirm whether you changed the drawing strategies or just kept the defaults.

Comment: Since you haven't replied I can't help you further.  Although reading your second comment again I can say part of the problem is you don't seem to understand that just because you don't have a badugi to start doesn't mean you won't have one at showdown.  That is what the drawing rounds are for.

Comment: Would the one who voted this down care to specify an actual problem with the badugi simulator (the only web-based simulator available) or would you rather hide behind anonymity with nothing valuable to contribute?